# Is it possible to call google analytics to add events programatically using c# with event created date

Tags: c#, google-analytics

Am looking for a way to add my application usage data into google analytics. What I have is in sql db, all the app usage info like user, the device, and the operation performed and the date and time at which this event was performed; I want to get these info into google analytics using c# and wanted to know if there is any way to do this. I have done quite some research using google and nugget and could only find packages which allow to fire events from apps and not really what I want also, with those I cant record the time.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible, because Analytics does not accept time information as parameter.

The closest is probably [Queue Time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) in the Measurement Protocol - the intended use case is to record hits that happend while a device was offline. Queue Time is an offset, the difference between the time a hit happened and the time now (i.e. if you record the hit a 1.00 am and send it 2 am the queue time would be 3600000 (1 hour in milliseconds)). The caveat is that "Values greater than four hours may lead to hits not being processed.".

So if you're app sends the hits every four hours you should be able to do this via the Measurement Protocol, else I guess you are out of luck.

Comment: Is it possible to get the satistics of any user , like how many videos they uploaded certain time frame